# How to programmatically reset a perspective in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-plugin

Is there a way to programmatically reset a perspective in Eclipse?

Comment: Why you need to do this?

Comment: Because I want to see all my perspectives with the default layout when i switch from one to another

Answer (score 3):

To reset a perspective, use `IWorkbenchPage#resetPerspective()`. The method will reset the current perspective to the state that is defined in the corresponding perspective descriptor.

Comment: Ok, but how can I reset the state from the descriptor? For example I have modified the layout and I want to get the default layout of the perspective?

Comment: @Me1999 Did you try out `resetPerspective`? That's exactly what it does. It restores the initial layout of the perspective, i.e. what's defined in the `plugin.xml` and `IPerspectiveFactory`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want preserve all your settings, simply copy the

**.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings**

directory into your desired workspace directory